# Importing bpy.types malfunctions in custom script directory

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on

Why can't `bpy` work properly when a script is loaded from a custom file directory?
Given that there is a file on `C:\scripts\addons` and it contains `example.py`, which appear in the Blender addon list. The problem is that in the code, several imports are called referencing `bpy.types`. The script unfortunately fails because `bpy.types` is an unknown location. How can this be fixed?

Comment: This also is happening to me when I try to install Amd Radeon ProRender Addon - Ubuntu 22.04 - Blender 4.0 (snap version).

Comment: The reason it was not working for me was because of Python API changes in 4.0. I'd recommend that for anyone experiencing the same issue, read the release notes related to Python for Blender 4.0. For issues with addons, maybe contact the authors.